# CFWheels - updateByKey() - The key argument contains an invalid value

Tags: model-view-controller, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11, cfwheels

```
<cfset  result = model("user").updateByKey(
                     key=authUser.user_id
                    , encryption_key=local.encryptionKey
                )>
```

The code above returns the following error in cfwheels:

> The key argument contains an invalid value.
>
> Suggested action
>
> The key argument contains a list, however this table doesn't have a
>   composite key. A list of values is allowed for the key argument, but
>   this only applies in the case when the table contains a composite key.

Now I have resolved this by using the update all method like this:

```
<cfset recordsReturned = model("user").updateAll(
          encryption_key=local.encryptionKey
         , where="user_id=#authUser.user_id#"
     )>
```

I've checked the database and cannot find duplicate primary keys. I've also tried setting the `instantiated=false` argument in the `updateByKey` method but that did not work either. Any explanation as to why this might happen would be appreciated.
ps: the closest thing i have to a primary key in the table apart from the user_id is the email_address which is unique so as not to allow duplicates.

Comment: What was the value of authUser.user_id that caused the error?